# Java Variable Scope Global

Tags: java, android, variables, methods, scope

im trying to understand variable scope with simple example.
I need help with this code

```
package com.varialescope.examplevariablescope;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button buttonOne;
private Button buttonTwo;
private String mText = "Hello World";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Initialialize UI elements

    buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_two);

    //Button One click listener

    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Set new text

            mText = "ONE";

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mText,      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //Button Two click listener

    buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

How can i access to mText string from click listener method ?

and how can i set a new string for mText clicking button One and make it accessible globally?

thanks for help

Comment: What is the problem? Haven't you accessed `mText` from within `OnClickListener`?

Comment: You're already accessing `mtext`, but if you want to be explicit, qualify like this: `MainActivity.this.mText`

Comment: Can you run the app? I strongly believe that it should crash as soon as you start it

Comment: Yes @iulian the app crash. I cant understand how to set new global variable text clicking on button one then retrieve text clicking button two

Comment: I think that you code does what you want if you fix the crash. To do that, change `buttonOne` in `buttonTwo` where you do the second findViewById. The problem is that you assign 2 values to the same object, and the other one is null, thing that leads to crash

Answer (score 1):

you create `anonymous` class Object for `clicklistener` any `anonymous` class or inner class object has information about the outside class object , then it had the right to access the methods and variables of the outside class object

Comment: In this way the app crash. I cant understand how to set new global variable text clicking on button one then retrieve text clicking button two

Comment: it doesn't have reason to crash .. can you give us the error msg ?